# event click jquery doesn't work in backbone.js

Tags: jquery, events, backbone.js, click

I want to ask something in backbone.js, why my click event doesn't work but if it uses hover, it will work.
So this is the code

uses hover event :

```
maps.fetch({
            data: params,
            success: function (collection, response) {

                //console.log(response);

                var data = null;
                if (response.status === "success"){
                    data = response.data;
                }

                var $tooltip = $('#tooltip-summary');

                $('.land').hover(function() {

                    var html = '';

                    var id = $(this).attr('id');
                    var position = $(this).position();

                    if(data !== null){
                        var map = data[id];

                        $('#province_name').text(map.province_name);

                        if(map.values === undefined || map.values === null){
                            html += '<tr>';
                            html += '<td class="text-center" colspan="7"> Data not found </td>';
                            html += '</tr>';
                        }else{
                            _.each(map.values, function(value) {

                                var img_arrow = '';

                                if(value.price_weekly > 0){
                                    img_arrow = '<img src="assets/img/arrow_up.png"/>';

                                }else if(value.price_weekly < 0){
                                    img_arrow = '<img src="assets/img/arrow_down.png"/>';
                                }

                                html += '<tr>';
                                html += '<td>'+ value.product_name +'</td>';
                                html += '<td>'+ value.price_buy_avg_fmt +'</td>';
                                html += '<td>'+ value.price_sell_avg_fmt +'</td>';
                                html += '<td>'+ img_arrow+' '+value.price_weekly_fmt +'</td>';
                                html += '<td>'+ value.total_volume_fmt +'</td>';
                                html += '<td>'+ value.market_share_percentage_store_fmt +'</td>';
                                html += '<td>'+ value.market_share_percentage_asi_fmt +'</td>';
                                html += '</tr>';
                            });
                        }

                    }else{
                        html = '';
                        html += '<tr>';
                        html += '<td class="text-center" colspan="7"> Data not found </td>';
                        html += '</tr>';
                    }

                    $tbody.html(html);

                    $tooltip.css({
                        display: 'block',
                        position: 'absolute',
                        top: ((position.top+60)-mapPosition.top)+'px',
                        left: ((position.left+73)-mapPosition.left)+'px',
                    });
                }, function() {
                    //console.log('on mouseout');
                    //$('#tooltip-summary').css('display', 'none');
                });
            }
        });
```

use click event :

```
maps.fetch({
            data: params,
            success: function (collection, response) {

                //console.log(response);

                var data = null;
                if (response.status === "success"){
                    data = response.data;
                }

                var $tooltip = $('#tooltip-summary');

                $('.land').click(function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();

                    var html = '';

                    var id = $(this).attr('id');
                    var position = $(this).position();

                    if(data !== null){
                        var map = data[id];

                        $('#province_name').text(map.province_name);

                        if(map.values === undefined || map.values === null){
                            html += '<tr>';
                            html += '<td class="text-center" colspan="7"> Data not found </td>';
                            html += '</tr>';
                        }else{
                            _.each(map.values, function(value) {

                                var img_arrow = '';

                                if(value.price_weekly > 0){
                                    img_arrow = '<img src="assets/img/arrow_up.png"/>';

                                }else if(value.price_weekly < 0){
                                    img_arrow = '<img src="assets/img/arrow_down.png"/>';
                                }

                                html += '<tr>';
                                html += '<td>'+ value.product_name +'</td>';
                                html += '<td>'+ value.price_buy_avg_fmt +'</td>';
                                html += '<td>'+ value.price_sell_avg_fmt +'</td>';
                                html += '<td>'+ img_arrow+' '+value.price_weekly_fmt +'</td>';
                                html += '<td>'+ value.total_volume_fmt +'</td>';
                                html += '<td>'+ value.market_share_percentage_store_fmt +'</td>';
                                html += '<td>'+ value.market_share_percentage_asi_fmt +'</td>';
                                html += '</tr>';
                            });
                        }

                    }else{
                        html = '';
                        html += '<tr>';
                        html += '<td class="text-center" colspan="7"> Data not found </td>';
                        html += '</tr>';
                    }

                    $tbody.html(html);

                    $tooltip.css({
                        display: 'block',
                        position: 'absolute',
                        top: ((position.top+60)-mapPosition.top)+'px',
                        left: ((position.left+73)-mapPosition.left)+'px',
                    });
                }, function() {
                    //console.log('on mouseout');
                    //$('#tooltip-summary').css('display', 'none');
                });
            }
        });
```

I checked the console, the click event didn't fire the code.
Is there any wrong in my code ? Grateful for any advice.
Thankyou

Comment: Because you are passing two anonymous functions to `click()` method, so the first is used as data event for the second one which is doing nothing...  See [DOC](https://api.jquery.com/click/#click-eventData-handler)

Comment: .....! just caught it...^^ @A.Wolff

Comment: thankyou for the explanation and helping me fix the code ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per **@A.woff**'s comment, you have to put one callback, otherwise the first function will be used as eventData for the second callback and second callback is doing nothing. So remove this:

```
, function() {
    //console.log('on mouseout');
    //$('#tooltip-summary').css('display', 'none');
}
```

Currently you are doing this:

```
$(selector).click(eventData, handler);
```

What is says first parameter [***`eventData`***](https://api.jquery.com/click/#click-eventData-handler) is the first anonymous function you passed will be used as `data` to get it in the `handler` which is your second anonymous function which is just blank.

```
$('.land').click(function(event) { // <----this one is treated as "eventData"
    event.preventDefault();
    // other code
}, function() {   // <----------and this one treated as handler for the click.
    //console.log('on mouseout');
    //$('#tooltip-summary').css('display', 'none');
});
```

Comment: I want to ask something, so event click only have one callback different with event hover that has two callback ?

Comment: @ResaRamdiansyah `.hover()` is a shorthand method which works for mouseenter,mouseleave.